# Reshaping pandas dataframe with count option

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Currently, I have this dataframe in pandas:

```
     year product
8    2016       apples
15   2016       kiwis
17   2016       mango
24   2016       mango
32   2016       mango
34   2016       peach
41   2017       peach
45   2017       peach
48   2017       peach
53   2017       bananas
54   2017       mango
72   2017       peach
73   2017       peach
```

I've been trying with melt and pivot, but alas no luck. Basically I want to count the instances of products I sold each year. What I want as dataframe is this:

```
       apples   peach   bananas kiwi mango
2016      1       1       0        1     3
2017      0       5       1        0     1
```

How can i reshape my df to the desired outcome?

Comment: You can try crosstab: `pd.crosstab(df['year'], df['product'])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
df1 = df.groupby(['year', 'product']).size().unstack(1, fill_value=0)

print(df1)

product  apples  bananas  kiwis  mango  peach
year
2016          1        0      1      3      1
2017          0        1      0      1      5
```

Or like mentioned in the comments:

```
pd.crosstab(df['year'], df['product'])
```

Comment: Thanks! Will study the groupby answer, but the crosstab was the solution I was looking for!